# Update command runs but returns -1 in Dapper

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I am using below code to update a record, it updates the specific record, but it returns -1 .

I am using Dapper to execute this procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Contact]
    @ContactId VARCHAR(50) ,
    @AccountId VARCHAR(50) ,
    @EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE MID bigint = 0

    SELECT TOP 1 MID = CID 
    FROM Type3002 
    WHERE ATTRIBUTE_2710 LIKE CAST(@EMailAddress AS VARCHAR(100))

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Type3002     
                   WHERE ContactId LIKE '%,' + CAST(@ContactId AS VARCHAR(100)) + ',%') 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Type3002
        SET ATTRIBUTE_2710 = LEFT(@EMailAddress, 50),
            ContactId = ContactId +','  + @ContactId,
            AccountId = AccountId ++','+ @AccountId 
        WHERE CID = MID
    END
    ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Type3002 
                        WHERE AccountId LIKE '%,' + @AccountId + ',%' 
                          AND ContactId LIKE '%,' + @ContactId)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Type3002
        SET AccountId = AccountId +','+ @AccountId 
        WHERE CID = MID
    END
END
```

Code that call this procedure is like this :

```
var result = await connection.ExecuteAsync("[Contact]",
```

Answer (score 2):

You procedure is missing a [`RETURN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement.

Note that in Transact-SQL, RETURN is seldom used (it can only be an `int` value, and cannot be NULL). OUTPUT parameters are much more useful.

Also `MID` should be `@MID` everywhere.